# Need excel 2010 popup to appear when file is opened

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This is my first time trying a VBA project. I didn't write the code and I'm not sure who did.

It works when I click the Run Sub Button but not when the file is opened which is the goal. How do I have the popup message appear when the file is opened?

See the image VBA for a snapshot of what I have.

[image]

Comment: We don't like images of code. Please [edit] the question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0):

From the dropdown select Workbook and Action as Open, and paste the code
See attached screenshot
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

Rename `cmdCheck_Click` to `Workbook_Open`.

This will cause your code to run,  when the workbook is opened.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196215.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396